A nodejs app not updates on change using docker container
I'm trying to use this github repository : https://github.com/Devansh-365/ceddit, an app with a client side, server side and MongoDB as database.All this is contained in a Docker images, the following Docker files:
Dockerfile:
FROM node:16-alpine

# Create App Directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install Dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent

# Install bcrypt
RUN npm install bcrypt

# Copy app source code
COPY . .

# Exports
EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["npm","start"]

and docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.8"

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: ceddit-server
    container_name: ceddit-node-server
    command: /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - app-network
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - app-network
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: ceddit-client
    container_name: ceddit-react-client
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  data-volume:
  node_modules:
  web-root:
    driver: local

when I try to make changes in files, it doesn't automatically refresh the volume in docker container, in server nodemon neither works.

If you use plain Node without Docker, does live reloading work?  If so, do you actually need Docker for a developer setup?
